# unget bytes to boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket

Tags: boost-asio

I need the two bytes to be read from the socket, and, if necessary, bring them back into the socket, so the next handler read them. how it can be implemented?
Thanks.

Comment: Not possible. Why not pass the two bytes to the next handler as part of the callback?

Answer (score 0):

you could use read_some and have a buffer the size of 2 in the beginning then resize the buffer on the second read.

Hope this helps

also

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/boost/asio/ssl/stream.hpp

peek function might be of more use to you.